# Postgres backup showing error no space left ,when there is already 2TB space

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have 2 servers A and B each with 2TB space, 32GB RAM, and Ubuntu Linux 20.04 OS.

My 'A' server contains timescaledb database(postgres version 12) which has around 800K tables (space occupied 500GB approx), now I want to make my new server 'B' a replica server for the 'A' server.

After following every step , now first i need to run 'pgbasebackup' command to take existing data backup and restore it into the 'B' server ,so that both servers are in same state.

I am running this command on server 'B':-

```
sudo pg_basebackup -h <IP of server 'A'> -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/ -U rep_user -P -v -R -X stream  -S slaveslot1
```

slot is already created that's why i am not pass -C flag.

my error logs are:-

```
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 10E/D71A8878 on timeline 1
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
pg_basebackup: error: could not create file "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main//base/16384/15340643_fsm": No space left on device
pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/"
```

How it can say that no space left on the device when it is 2TB free.

Comment: What do you get for `df -Ti /var/lib/postgresql/12/main`? Is there a docker container or something else that imposes disk quota?

Comment: No docker container is present, the server is totally free.

result of command df -Ti /var/lib/postgresql/12/main

`Filesystem     Type    Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on  


/dev/root      ext4 262144000 103520 262040480    1% /




`

Comment: Hard to say - ask your storage and operating system experts. But you are definitely out of disk, and that is no database problem.